# Push notification without firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have make an android app in android studio and push notification is send from firebase console. Now I want to send push notification from a screen(title, message and a button) which should be made in ionic instead of firebase console. Is there any who have do this before.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: This is simple a doc... i need a tutorial link...

Comment: Firebase notification is well documented by now. I have answered to a couple similar questions on SO. You may want to remove your question as it might be marked as duplicate. Nonetheless, if I understand your question correctly, you want to send a notification via your app to a user of that app. You can do so easily by running an instance of app server or do it via Firebase functions. See my detailed answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/47171620/5601401